# PHPWord file is corrupted on IIS Server

Tags: php, laravel, iis, phpword

I have PHP office integrated in a laravel application. It works when I run it on my xampp localhost, but when I use it on the IIS production server I get "We're sorry, we can't open text.docx because we found a problem with its contents. The file is corrupt and cannot be opened." I can click through two more error pop-ups warning me about "unreadable content" and then open the file. The file looks fine when I do finally get it opened.
The IIS server uses php version 5.6.14, libxml2 Version 2.9.2 with xml reader & writer enabled and Zend Extension 220131226.
Here is the offending code, I pulled the sections out and still have the same error so I know it's not my string formatting.
Also possibly relevant is that on both servers the document opens in "Read Mode" instead of "Print Layout". I would prefer it open in Print Layout.

```
$phpWord = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord();
$phpWord->getCompatibility()->setOoxmlVersion(15);      

$objWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($phpWord, 'Word2007');
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $client->last_name . '.docx"');
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Expires: 0');
$objWriter->save("php://output");
```

Answer (score 0):

If the code works on `XAMPP` I would wouldn't worry about the code. Try to match the environment and as much as possible. Running `PHP` on `IIS` is not the same as it would on a Linux environment.